# Get first value in column from CSV file in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, csv, asp.net-web-api

I am using this code in my Web Api to get data from a csv file, and plug that data into a Item List.

```
 private List<Item> ietms = new List<Item>();

        public ItemRepository()
        {
            string filename = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "App_Data\\items.csv";

            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename).Skip(1).ToList();

            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
            {
                var line = lines[i];

                var columns = line.Split('$');

                //get rid of newline characters in the middle of data lines
                while (columns.Length < 9)
                {
                    i += 1;
                    line = line.Replace("\n", " ") + lines[i];
                    columns = line.Split('$');
                }

                //Remove Starting and Trailing open quotes from fields
                columns = columns.Select(c => { if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(c) == false) { return c.Substring(1, c.Length - 2); } return string.Empty; }).ToArray();



                items.Add(new Item()
                {
                    Id = int.Parse(columns[0]),
                    Name = columns[1],
                    Description = columns[2],
                    Price = string.IsNullOrEmpty(columns[3].Trim()) ? null : (double?)double.Parse(columns[3]),
                    Weight = columns[8],
                    PhotoUrl = columns[7],
                    Category=columns[9]



                });
            }
        }
```

In the csv file one of the columns/value is structured like this:

```
Groups>Subgroup>item
```

or in some cases

```
MajorGroup|Groups>Subgroup>item
```

How do I pull out only the first value before the > or |, so that I would get the value as `Groups` in the first case and `MajorGroup` in the second, and store it in the `Category` property in the Item List, which is now just set to the entire value in column 9 which would return the whole string "Groups>Subgroup>item".

Comment: [Mandatory `don't roll your own CSV parser` link](http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp‎)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line before calling "Add item"

```
var temp = columns[9].Split('|', '>');
```

Then assign the category as follows.

```
Category = temp[0];
```

Based on: [MSDN String Method Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)

Comment: Can you please look at question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21538092/get-first-and-last-column-value-in-c-sharp. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this?

```
string data = "MajorGroup|Groups>Subgroup>item";
string groupOrCategory;

if (data.Contains('|'))
{
    groupOrCategory = data.Substring(0, data.IndexOf('|'));
}
else
{
    groupOrCategory = data.Substring(0, data.IndexOf('>'));
}

Console.WriteLine(groupOrCategory);
```